# Run and manipulate a java multithread class in jsf page

Tags: java, multithreading, web

How to run a multithreaded class (a method with many threads and need to pause and resume) in my Web Application?
I want to stop thread and stop it from my Web application in any time.
So how do I have to implement this problem?

Is it good to use application bean or other type beans?

Comment: Your bean will need to be at least SessionScoped or ApplicationScoped. Good or not depend from application to another. You could also use CRON, external JAVA application with sockets to start and stop, etc.

Comment: Mohammad - I have upvoted your question to incourage you to stay on stackoverflow.